# "x thinks it's people"--why "people" and not "a human"?

Tags: grammar, idioms

If I understand correctly, the phrase "x thinks it's people" is used to say that something (usually an animal) behaves like a human being. An example:

> Wherever you turn your head, you can see a tabby in a party hat or **a Siamese cat ‘playing chess like it thinks it’s people’**.

From: [*Oxford Dictionaries Blog*](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/04/cat-idioms/)

But why do we have here "people" instead of "a human"? I mean, to me the structure of this expression looks like this: one entity (an animal) is many entities (people). Or maybe "people" is not a noun here?

Comment: That is an awkward construction.  I prefer more formal grammar: `...a Siamese cat "playing chess as if it thinks itself a person."`

Comment: Yeah, as Crazy Eyes mentions, *it thinks it’s people* is now a saying or idiom that was popularized by its use on an episode of the TV show *The Simpsons.* Not every English speaker will have heard of it, or recognize the origin, because not everybody is a fan of the show.

Comment: One also notes that you can be a person without being human.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't a grammatical mistake, but a reference to an old *Simpsons* episode from 1994. The phrase is meant to be said in a condescending tone: "Aww, it thinks it's people!" It means exactly what you think it means. The grammatical error is done intentionally for comedic effect.

Comment: Was this phrase already popular in the '90s? Or has it become common recently thanks to meme culture?

Comment: A marathon of the Simpsons entire series collection was recently hosted on FXX.  Perhaps that's the reason you have heard this phrase?